# Convert String to date using Datawave Mule

Tags: string, date, type-conversion, mule

I want to convert a string "2016-04-09" to a date using datawave mule , any idea guys ?

When i use :

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  d1: "2016-04-09" as :date
}
```

i got `SUN Mar 09 00:00:00 CET 2016` as result but i want `'2016-04-09'` date type instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following expression,

```
foo: "2016-04-09" as :date {class : "java.util.Calendar", format : "yyyy-MM-dd"}
```

Answer (score 0):

here we go:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    foo: "2016-04-09" as :date
}
```

also take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#coerce-to-date).

Comment: the output is not that what i want :( , i got a result like this " SUN Mar 09 00:00:00 CET 2016" but i want a result like this " 2016-04-09" type date not string